# Do scaling runes keep scaling after lvl 18 in URF?

Tags: league-of-legends

In every other gamemode, champions will level up until 18. URF allows up to 26 levels.

Will runes keep scaling, or will it stop at lvl 18?

Comment: URF actually goes up to level 30. http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ultra_Rapid_Fire

Comment: @mbomb007 as of today, yes.

Comment: At the time of the asking of this question, it was also level 30. In fact, it was always level 30, as seen in the edit history. This is the same page but as it existed back then: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ultra_Rapid_Fire?oldid=2382135

Answer (score 1):

On the scaling runes, you can read amout Per level... not amount per level until level 18.

So the answer Here is YES it will scale until level 26.

HK

Comment: How about actually prooving your point with evidence.

Comment: You left out a crucial part I think. Additional to what you are saying the description of the runes reads further: "XX at champion level 18". So I'm not sure about your answer.

Comment: Although "xx at level 18" is just a way to say what that value is when multiplied by 18, not that it stops at that amount.

Comment: Level cap on URF is 30. http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ultra_Rapid_Fire

Answer (score 0):

As Karoui Haythem said, yes they do. It has been commonly tested.

After level 18, you will continue to gain stats based upon your scaling runes for each level.